# Should data be filtered in the front end or the back end when updating the URL?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database

I'm building my personal website where I want to implement a language change. So I have a key for each collection which decides what language the data will be in. I'm wondering if I should GET all the data then filter out what I don't need or simply do another request to my database when the url is changed by that specific language key. In my case, loading everything would not be ressource heavy since it's only a couple dozens entries at most. But I wonder where you draw the line where pulling too much information would become more demanding and if actually filtering out the information is less demanding than doing another request.

Answer (score 2):

It's always best to return only the data necessary from the backend. If your server can figure out the language needed (by looking in the incoming `header` for `accept-language` perhaps) and only get and return the specific data that is needed, that's the way to go.

If you push the filtering into the client-side/front-end then you expose some of your internal implementation and expose the javascript (or whatever) function that goes through the data. By doing that work on the server-side/back-end you benefit from

- the speed of the server
- reduce the size of your client side code
- avoid sending useless data across the wire

It's not a huge investment to do the filtering on the back-end even though the amount of data isn't large at this point, but it's more correct. Future you will thank you if things get larger or more complex.